# How to send sms with body or content in react native:expo

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, expo

I am using Linking in expo to send sms through expo like this:

```
 Linking.openURL("sms:123456789")
```

It opens the text message with this number with body blank so if I need something in body I have done like this:

```
  Linking.openURL("sms:123456789?body=test1234?")
```

but it doesn't work, How can I achieve this, any help would be thankful.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is not the same on both platforms so the one you are using only works on Android.

iOS: `Linking.openURL("sms:123456789&body=test1234?")` -> (notice the `&` instead of `?`)

Android: `Linking.openURL("sms:123456789?body=test1234")`

Anyway, since you are using Expo, you could use the [`SMS`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sms) module.

```
const isAvailable = await Expo.SMS.isAvailableAsync();
if (isAvailable) {
  const { result } = await Expo.SMS.sendSMSAsync(['123456789'], 'test1234');
}
```

Working example -> https://snack.expo.io/SyoGjwQZV

Comment: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAvailableAsync' of undefined

Comment: this exception occured @QoP

Comment: @Nivesh have you imported `Expo`? Looks like you forgot to import it, `import Expo from 'expo';`. I also created a Snack example so you can check it & play with it -> https://snack.expo.io/SyoGjwQZV

Comment: Does anyone know any alternative of `expo-sms` for bare react native project? @@

Answer (score 0):

See new Google Policy , by default SMS and CALL_LOG access deactivated ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.